# Triggering a pipeline and waiting for it to finish from another pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two different project repositories: my application repository, and an API repository. My application communicates with the API.

I want to set up some integration and E2E tests of my application. The application will need to use the latest version of the API project when running these tests.

The API project is already setup to deploy when triggered

```
deploy_integration_tests:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "deploying..."
  environment:
    name: integration_testing
  only:
    - triggers
```

My application has an integration testing job set up like this:

```
integration_test
  stage: integration_test
  script:
    - echo "Building and deploying API..."
    - curl.exe -X POST -F token=<token> -F ref=develop <url_for_api_trigger>
    - echo "Now running the integration test that depends on the API deployment..."
```

The problem I am having is that the trigger only queues the API pipeline (both projects are using the same runner) and continues before the API pipeline has actually run.

Is there a way to wait for the API pipeline to run before trying to run the integration test?

I can do something like this:

```
integration_test_dependency
  stage: integration_test_dependency
  script:
    - echo "Building and deploying API..."
    - curl.exe -X POST -F token=<token> -F ref=develop <url_for_api_trigger>

integration_test
  stage: integration_test
  script:
    - echo "Now running the integration test that depends on the API deployment..."
```

But that still doesn't grantee that the API pipeline runs and finishes before moving on to the integration_test stage.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No news about this issue and whether it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible. There are some issues in gitlab about this:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25457
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29347
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22972
- etc

Your best bet is to lend weight to some of these issues.

Comment: This answer is already deprecated. Gitlab already has https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html as the solution to this.

Answer (score 18):

I've come across this limitation recently and have set up an image that can be re-used to make this a simple build step:

https://gitlab.com/finestructure/pipeline-trigger

So in your case this would look like this using my image:

```
integration_test
  stage: integration_test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/finestructure/pipeline-trigger
  script:
    - echo "Now running the integration test that depends on the API deployment..."
    - trigger -a <api token> -p <token> <project id>
```

Just use the project id (instead of having to find the whole url) and create a personal access token, which you supply here (best do this via a secret).

The reason the latter is needed is for polling the pipeline status. You can trigger without it but getting the result needs API authorisation.

See the project description for more details and additional things pipeline-trigger can do.

Comment: sir, tell me please, when we use this module, can we trigger pipeline with some variables?

Comment: Yes, via `trigger ... -e foo=bar`. See the README for details.

Comment: I have run into problems with multi project pipeline where the context is not shared due to a bug. I was stuck, until I saw this. 

This is awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone else is here looking for this on triggered pipelines from the ci yaml, you can use the keyword `depend` for `strategy` to ensure the pipeline waits for the triggered pipeline:

```
    trigger: 
      project: group/triggered-repo
      strategy: depend
```

Comment: This seems to not allow for using any other trigger token than the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` :(

Comment: Trigger bridge-jobs do not allow to use environment keyword, it is also not possible to retry them, so still triggering+polling via API is more capable.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the exact same feature, so I wrote a python3 utility to do it.

See [Python Commander on GitHub](https://github.com/cfriedt/pipeline-commander).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me was a combination of trigger:strategy = depend and acyclic directed graphs usage in the downstream stage

```
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
    - downstream
(...)
trigger-1:
  stage: downstream
  trigger:
    project: group/project1
    branch: main
    strategy: depend  # <---- wait for completion to mark this as success
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
      yaml_variables: false

trigger-2:
  stage: downstream
  needs: [ "trigger-1" ] # <-- ensures the first triggered job is completed
  trigger:
    project: group/project2
    branch: main
    #strategy: depend  <---- don't wait for completion to mark this as success
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
      yaml_variables: false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `strategy: depend` to wait for the downstream pipeline to finish, make sure to use [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#trigger-job-mirror-status-of-downstream-pipeline-when-cancelled) (May 2023)

> ### Trigger job mirror status of downstream pipeline when cancelled
>
> Previously, a trigger job configured with `strategy: depends` mirrored the job status of the downstream pipeline.
> If the downstream pipeline was in the `running` status, the trigger job was also marked as `running`.
>
> Unfortunately, if the downstream job did not comnplete and had a status `canceled`, the trigger job’s status was inaccurately `failed`.
>
> In this release, we have updated trigger jobs with `strategy: depend` to reflect the downstream’s pipelines’s statis accurately.
> When a downstream pipeline is cancelled, the trigger also shows canceled.
>
> This change may have an impact on your existing pipelines, especially if you have jobs that rely on the trigger job’s status being marked as failed. We recommend reviewing your pipeline configurations and making any necessary adjustments to accommodate this change in behavior.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerstrategy) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/220794).